# Windows clock keeps falling behind, even after CMOS change

Tags: windows, date-time, cmos

The clock on my computer keeps falling behind and the only way to correct it is by pressing 'Sync' in the Date/Time settings. I have changed the CMOS battery to a brand new one but the problem persists. Is there a way to diagnose/fix this?

To clarify, my time will not progress as time should. For example, after an hour of being on my computer, the clock can randomly go back a few hours. It is hard to pinpoint exactly how the time changes. When I turn my computer on the next day, the time shown is nowhere near the actual time.

Comment: Are you dual booting Linux? When you say “fall behind” what do you mean exactly? If you are dual booting have you configured Windows on Unix time?  [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: I am not using Linux and there is no mention of that in my question or tags. I am not dual booting and my sole OS is Windows 10. I will edit my post to clarify, but when I say fall behind I mean it will suddenly go back an hour, or just will not progress as time should. When I turn my computer on, it will show a completely random time on my clock until I sync it. It then fails to keep up and an hour later it seems to have only increased by half an hour, for example.

Comment: 1)Did you set the time in BIOS/UEFI after changing the battery? 2)When the time is off have you re-verified what time shows in BIOS/UEFI? This would indicate if BIOS or Windows setting is at fault. 3)Is the timezones set correctly? Maybe post a pic of your time settings as it can sync automatically 4)is this PC part of a domain? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/windows-time-service-tools-and-settings
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/time

Comment: @gregg 1) The date/time is showing as correct in the BIOS when I checked a second ago (but this was after I had pressed sync in Windows before restarting). 2) Good call, I will check this when it goes out of sync later. 3) Timezone is set correctly 4) Not part of a domain

Comment: I don't believe when windows syncs the time it adjusts the BIOS time, but I could be wrong. This is staring to look like something in Windows is causing. You could look at your startup tab in task manager right-click at the top headers to add column cmd to find location of items then see if any might be adjusting time. You could disable them temporarily. Maybe look at msconfig services tab then tick box to exclude Microsoft services. Microsoft has an article that shows how to 'clean boot' so only windows stuff loads automatically. Might try safe mode too as that loads only minimal things

Comment: Clean boot how-to: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-da2f9573-6eec-00ad-2f8a-a97a1807f3dd